# java.lang.NullPointerException using preferencemanager

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-logcat

Logcat error:

```
01-21 07:23:04.021: E/AndroidRuntime(361): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException }
```

In what i believe to be this piece of java code:

```
while (date.equals("01:00:00") || bSet);
    int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(ids.length);
    String last = ((getResources().getString(ids[randomNumber])));
    tv.setText(last);
    edit.putString(last, null);
    edit.commit();
```

i have previously set up preferences as so, just before my oncreate method:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
```

Comment: All executable code in Java must be inside a method.

Comment: use `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

context is not available before `onCreate` so you cannot use `this`
here:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
```

put this inside onCreate like:

```
  SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
```

and in onCreate

```
  prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  edit = prefs.edit();
```